# Plotting Multiple Graphs in GRAL

Tags: java, swing, graph, plot

I'm currently using the library GRAL for graphing out lines and data.  For some reason, I'm having trouble graphing multiple lines on the same XY Plot.  Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import de.erichseifert.gral.data.DataTable;
import de.erichseifert.gral.plots.XYPlot;
import de.erichseifert.gral.plots.lines.DefaultLineRenderer2D;
import de.erichseifert.gral.plots.lines.LineRenderer;
import de.erichseifert.gral.plots.points.PointRenderer;
import de.erichseifert.gral.ui.InteractivePanel;

public class GraphTest extends JFrame {
    public GraphTest(double x1, double y1) {

        //SETS DEFAULTS FOR JFRAME
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 400);

        //CREATES A DATA TABLE AND RUNS A LOOP TO INCREMENTALLY PLOT OUT POINTS OF A SINE CURVE ON THE STEP .25
        DataTable data = new DataTable(Double.class, Double.class);
        for (double x = -5.0; x <= 5.0; x+=0.25) {
            double y = 5.0*Math.sin(x);
            data.add(x, y);
        }

        //PLOT OUT DATA AND SET XYPLOT IN JFRAME, THEN CONNECT LINES AND CHANGE COLORS
        XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(data);
        getContentPane().add(new InteractivePanel(plot));
        LineRenderer lines = new DefaultLineRenderer2D();
        plot.setLineRenderer(data, lines);
        Color color = new Color(0.0f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        plot.getPointRenderer(data).setColor(color);
        plot.getLineRenderer(data).setColor(color);

        //PLOT OUT A POINT (4,5) ON THE SAME GRAPH AS THE SINE GRAPH
        DataTable data2 = new DataTable(Double.class, Double.class);
        data2.add(x1, y1);
        XYPlot plot2 = new XYPlot(data2);
        //getContentPane().add(new InteractivePanel(plot2));
        //plot2.setLineRenderer(data2, lines);
        //plot2.getPointRenderer(data2).setColor(color);
        //plot2.getLineRenderer(data2).setColor(color);
    }

    public static void main(double x1, double y1) {
        GraphTest frame = new GraphTest(x1, y1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The program runs fine the way it is, but I un-comment the following lines to make it plot two graphs on the same plot:

```
    //getContentPane().add(new InteractivePanel(plot2));
    //plot2.setLineRenderer(data2, lines);
    //plot2.getPointRenderer(data2).setColor(color);
    //plot2.getLineRenderer(data2).setColor(color);
```

And the JFrame just goes blank and the program seems to freeze.  I'm a beginner to the library GRAL (I just started using it today), so please excuse my lack of expertise.  Also, FYI, this code is being run via a command in the same package but another class with the following code:

```
GraphTest.main(4,5);
```

The problem is that I just am really not sure how to plot two graphs (a sine curve and a point) on the same XY Plot.  Lastly, here is an image of what the current code looks like when it is run:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, but here is how I solved the same problem:

On the part where you create the XY Plot, just add more data sources.

From

```
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(data);
```

To

```
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(data, moreData);
```

Make sure to style both data points individually.

Comment: Sorry for not answering my own question earlier, but I actually figured it out myself later. But thanks, anyway.